# jQuery set variable to -1 if up arrow key pressed or to increment variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/fCAAY/68/)

I use jkey to simplify the usage on detecting which key is pressed.

**Question**
What i want is when any other except up arrow key is pressed set the value of `count` to `-1` and if up arrow key is pressed do it just like in the code.

Is there a way out by using the jKey plugin ?
if not then how do i do it with normal jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This obviously doesn't get you exactly where you want to go but it should get you started.

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="myBigText"></textarea>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myBigText").keydown(function(evt) {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
        if(charCode == 38) {
            alert("This is the up arrow key");
        } else {
            alert("This is not the up arrow");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jKey doesn't work this way. You have to explicitly tell it what you want to look for.  There's no "any key" option.  You should [fork it on github](https://github.com/OscarGodson/jKey) and add in this feature.

Comment: Then is there a way by jquery ?

Comment: Sure! Use the standard keyboard events. http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/

Comment: I have been having problems in doing that. If i want to use the keydown() even how do i detect if the down key is pressed ?

Comment: Any key would be the exact opposite reason to use jKey :) jQuery.keydown, keyup, keypress all work as "any key".